# NullPointerException for my States in my DFA?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, dfa

I can't figure out why I am getting a NullPointerException in my code.
I am trying to write simulator for a DFA and I have made my a Node type class that holds my states as seen below,

```
import java.util.Map;


class State{
        //fields
        Map<String,State> nextStates;

        public State passChar(String putIn){
            if(!nextStates.containsKey(putIn)){
                return null; 
            }
            return nextStates.get(putIn);
        }

        /**
         * Add a state that this state connects to.
         * @param sta the state that this state connects to when
         * a letter in the alphabet is passed to it.
         * @param pass the letter that is passed to it.
         */
        public void addNextState(String pass,State sta){
            nextStates.put(pass,sta);
        }
    }
```

I have tried I the main is in my driving class
and is as such,

```
//Setting up my Q
        State q1 = new State();
        State q2 = new State();
        q1.addNextState("1", q1); //this is where my exception is thrown.
        q1.addNextState("0", q2);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at State.addNextState(State.java:25)
    at DFA.main(DFA.java:100)
```

Comment: You never initialized `nextStates`, so it's null. When you try to access its `.put` method, NPE.

Comment: The problem in this line of code:

    nextStates.put(pass,sta);

Because nextStates is not initialized yet.

You should add `new HashMap<String, State>();` to be like that:

     Map<String,State> nextStates = new HashMap<String, State>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to initialize the `Map`:

```
Map<String,State> nextStates;
```

Where are you doing it ? Something like this:

```
Map<String,State> nextStates = new HasMap <>();
```

That's the reason for NullPointerException.